# How to capture the Server response in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a Java bean class that invokes the Http request and get the response. I need to send this response back to Web page. Need your advise how to put the server response as a link in the .xhtml

Java Code

```
        String message = "http://localhost:8085/jenkins/api/xml";
        //auditDetails.insertLoginDetails(_uName, systemDate, actionType, action);
        //auditDetails.insertLoginDetails("test", systemDate, actionType, action);
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
    return "successPage.xhtml";
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use commandLink attribute to achieve this

```
<h:commandLink value="#{message.message}"
     action="#{managedBeanName.message}" 
      rendered="#{managedBeanName.message ne ''}" />
```

although you need to declare the message variable globally not method local variable and setters and getters required for that variable.